# In Pandas, how to do some arithmetic calculations for specific consecutive columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

In the following code, I like to calculate the total percentage change for Value only when Code is 'b'. The expected answer is 0.6 (which is 3/4 * 8/10).

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
x = pd.DataFrame({'Code':['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'a'], 'Value': np.arange(13)})

   Code  Value
0     a      0
1     a      1
2     a      2
3     b      3
4     b      4
5     a      5
6     a      6
7     a      7
8     b      8
9     b      9
10    b     10
11    a     11
12    a     12
```

I tried with `df.groupby`, but as there are two groups of 'b', it does not do what I expected.

Thank you very much for your time in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're trying to calculate requires you to group

1. consecutive rows
2. sharing a property about their column values.

Notice that grouping consecutive rows is grouping data based on a property of the *index*. A common and very flexible trick you can do in cases like this is to introduce a new *column* that stores the property of the index you care about.

In this case, you can track in a column how many times the value in the `Code` column has changed between consecutive rows:

```py
(x.assign(code_changed=lambda df: df.Code != df.Code.shift(),
          ordered_code=lambda df: df.code_changed.cumsum())
```

```
    Code    Value   code_changed    ordered_code
0   a       0       True            1
1   a       1       False           1
2   a       2       False           1
3   b       3       True            2
4   b       4       False           2
5   a       5       True            3
6   a       6       False           3
7   a       7       False           3
8   b       8       True            4
9   b       9       False           4
10  b       10      False           4
11  a       11      True            5
12  a       12      False           5
```

The `ordered_code` column contains the exact grouping information you're looking for. You can then reach the output you're hoping for by restricting to rows with `Code` equal to `'b'` and aggregating `Value`s:

```py
(x.assign(code_changed=lambda df: df.Code != df.Code.shift(),
          ordered_code=lambda df: df.code_changed.cumsum())
  .pipe(lambda df: df[df.Code == 'b'])
  .groupby('ordered_code')
  .Value
  .agg(lambda values: values.iloc[0] / values.iloc[-1])
  .prod())
```

This outputs

```
0.6000000000000001
```

as desired.

Answer (score 0):

Then take whatever your desired values are from pct_change and multiply them together as you wish.

```
pct_change = df.loc[df['Code'] == 'b'].pct_change()
```

Multiply the first and third value.

```
pct_change.iloc[[1]].values * pct_change.iloc[[3]].values
```

Or if you have multiple values you can write a loop to get different rows of pct_change.

Comment: Thank you for the answer :). I tried with 'pct_change()', but it also calculates a percentage change between 4 (the last element of the first 'b' group) and 8 (the first element of the second 'b' group).

Comment: You can grab the first and third item from the list and multiply them together. Added to the code

Comment: Thank you for the help :). It works, but I wanted to automate it rather than choosing rows manually. I still learn a lot from you.